# Toshiba Satellite C660 not Booting at All

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, laptop, boot

I have a Toshiba Satellite laptop, and it was working fine but now it's not booting at all. From some days, it running slow and hang sometimes. I was using Windows 8 Pro on this. But now it even does not boot! When I turn it on, a boot logo appears and after that an underscore sign (_) blinks and become stable and nothing happens after that. I tried re-installing Windows 8 again also I tried Windows 7 and Ubuntu but no success till now. Sometimes it boots but most of the time it fails.

One more important thing is that when I change SATA mode from AHCI to Compatibility from BIOS, it boots but it's very slow. Please tell me what's going on? Is this a hard disk problem?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is your hard drive is failing, or has failed. With another computer download the utility to test the drive from the hard drive manufacturers site. It will be available as a file that will create a bootable cd.

FWIW, many times the hard drive is trashed enough to keep the pc from booting, but not trashed enough to keep from pulling your data off.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Toshiba Satellite C660.  I suggest upgrading the drivers for your IDE ATA/ATAPI Controller (see device manager) from [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/20768/AHCI-Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Driver-for-Intel-Desktop-Boards-)

PS: As a solution to my Laptop I tried another HDD and it worked!